# How do I receive HID reports using libusb-1.0?

Tags: c, usb, hid, libusb, libusb-1.0

I have a USB HID scale that I need to fetch the weighing reports from.  I am able to do this on Linux by reading 7 bytes at a time from `/dev/hidraw#`, but I would like to get the same information using libusb-1.0.

Even when I do get some non-null bytes, I get error -9: `LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE`

I am attempting to use a control transfer like so:

```
#define WEIGH_REPORT_SIZE 7

    /*
     * Open a handle to the found scale
     */
    libusb_open(dev, &handle);
#ifdef __linux__
    libusb_detach_kernel_driver(handle, 0);
#endif
    libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);

    /*
     * Try to transfer data about status
     *
     */
    unsigned char data[WEIGH_REPORT_SIZE];
    unsigned int len = libusb_control_transfer(
        handle,
        LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS |
            LIBUSB_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE,
        HID_REPORT_GET,
        //wValue => hid report, no report ID
        0x0100,
        0x00,   //windex => interface 0
        data,
        WEIGH_REPORT_SIZE,    //wLength
        10000 //timeout => 10 sec
        );
    int i;
    printf("Got %d bytes from control transfer:\n", len);
    for(i = 0; i < WEIGH_REPORT_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%x\n", data[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example to read from a USB HID card reader using libusb-win -

http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2011/02/read-from-magtek-card-swipe-reader-in.html

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to do it.

Answer (score 3):

HID uses Interrupt Transfer AFAIK. You need to rewrite your code to use these. And have a look at thouse descriptors - they tell you which interface to use.

That said I think its much easier to use /dev/hdiraw# then libusb in *this* case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another value for `wValue` (`0x0300`, for example).

Also check `bmRequestType` and `bRequest` parameters: `bmRequestType` must be equal to `0xA1`, `bRequest` — `0x01`.